# Pycharm - Update button not working

Tags: pycharm

Is not a big problem, just annoying.

When I open PyCharm, a notification warns me about a new update. However, when in the Update Window, the Download button doesn't work.

Although this version is EAP, this is happening since version 2016.1

O.S.: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bits

[image]

**UPDATE**

Problem solved downloading a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'official' JetBrains answer is:

"Please reinstall manually from http://www.jetbrains.com/..."

[Soruce](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000781510-Not-possible-to-update-IntelliJ-Download-button-inactive)